# How does ActiveRecord::Error.type affect validation error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's a code fragment from a Rails project I am working on:

```ruby
if has_youtube && has_vimeo
  record.errors.add(:video_link, type: 'A project cannot have videos from both YouTube and Vimeo')
  return
end

if record.video_link.present?
  record.errors.add(:video_link, message: "This doesn't look like a valid YouTube or Vimeo link. Please try again.")
else
  record.errors.add(:video_link, :blank, message: 'You need to complete this field to register.')
end
```

The documentation for the [ActiveRecord::Error](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Error.html) class and the [Active Record Validation Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message) both explain  `message`, but neither explain `type`. What is `type`, what impact does it have on validation errors, and where is it documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html contains some information on it:

> add(attribute, type = :invalid, **options) Adds a new error of
> `type` on `attribute`. More than one error can be added to the same
> `attribute`. If no `type` is supplied, `:invalid` is assumed.

```ruby
person.errors.add(:name)
# Adds <#ActiveModel::Error attribute=name, type=invalid>
person.errors.add(:name, :not_implemented, message: "must be implemented")
# Adds <#ActiveModel::Error attribute=name, type=not_implemented, options={:message=>"must be implemented"}>

person.errors.messages
# => {:name=>["is invalid", "must be implemented"]}
```

> If `type` is a string, it will be used as error message.
>
> If `type` is a symbol, it will be translated using the appropriate scope
> (see `generate_message`).

```ruby
person.errors.add(:name, :blank)
person.errors.messages
# => {:name=>["can't be blank"]}

person.errors.add(:name, :too_long, { count: 25 })
person.errors.messages
# => ["is too long (maximum is 25 characters)"]
```

> If `type` is a proc, it will be called, allowing for things like
> `Time.now` to be used within an error.
>
> If the `:strict` option is set to `true`, it will raise
> `ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed` instead of adding the error.
> `:strict` option can also be set to any other exception.